# SQL Server : how to declare variable in condition case when

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a problem when running queries with a 'case when'. so I want to create a variable to hold the value of the results of the query 'select' to other tables. like the example below. please help me to get the results I want. thank you.

```
SELECT 
    a.field1, a.field2, 
    a.field3 =
      CASE 
         WHEN a.field1 = 'alfa' 
            THEN
         WHEN
            -- I want to declare variable to check get value from another table with query select and condition 'WHERE' with variable declare
var varTest = (SELECT TOP 1 b.field1 FROM Table2 as b WHERE b.field2=a.field2) Then
    if varTest = 'actif' then
    SELECT (c.field4 * C.field5) as hasil FROM Table2 as c WHERE c.field1=varTest)    
       ELSE 
           a.field3 
    END                                                         
FROM  
    Table1 a(NOLOCK)  
WHERE 
    a.field1 = 'alfa'
```

This is sample data :

```
field1 | field2 | field3 | > Table1
alfa     idAlfa      0
beta     idBeta      0
carlie   idCarlie    0


field1 | field2 | field4 | field5 | > Table2
actif    idAlfa     80       5
pasif    idBeta     50       5
other    idCarlie   10       5
```

Result :

```
field1 | field2  | field3
alfa     idAlfa    400
beta     idBeta    250
carlie   idCarlie  50
```

Comment: It sounds like you need a [table variable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188927.aspx) as you want it to hold the results of a query? But looking at your query you've commented, it only returns 1 row and column, so declaring a non-table variable would be sufficient.

Comment: @JonathonOgden he want to do this in 1 single query.

Comment: So, what I need to improve my query from the example above? if I may ask you for help to fix the query like I mean.thanks @JonathonOgden

Comment: @user2538170 could you show some sample data of the results you expect please?

Comment: hey @JonathonOgden look. i write for example data in table. thanks for help me...

Comment: So you want `field3` to be `field4 * field5` if it is the actif (active) record and 0 for all other records?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like this is what you intended. Hard to be entirely sure. It's also possible that this isn't the most efficient query as it's generally a good idea to avoid subqueries inside `case` expressions.

```
a.field3 =
    CASE WHEN a.field1 = 'alfa' THEN
        CASE WHEN (
                SELECT TOP 1 b.field1 FROM Table2 as b
                WHERE b.field2 = a.field
            ) = 'actif'
            THEN (
                SELECT c.field4 * C.field5 as hasil FROM Table2 as c
                WHERE c.field1 = 'actif'
            )    
            ELSE a.field3
        END
        ELSE null
    END
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a variable of any type to accomplish this.

A simple `JOIN` and `CASE` will get the active (actif) record, calculate your `field4 * field5` result (hasil) or use 0 for all passive (pasif) or other records like so:

```
SELECT 
    a.field1, 
    a.field2,
    CASE b.field1 -- check id...
        WHEN 'actif'
            THEN b.field4 * b.field5 -- if 'actif' record, calculate result
        ELSE
            a.field3 -- not the 'actif' record, use default value
    END AS hasil
FROM Table1 AS a -- join the two tables by id name
LEFT JOIN Table2 AS b
ON a.field2 = b.field2;
```

If you're using SQL Server 2012, you can condense this `CASE` statement by using `IIF`:

```
SELECT 
    a.field1, 
    a.field2,
    IIF(b.field1 = 'actif', b.field3 * b.field4, a.field3) AS hasil
FROM Table1 AS a
LEFT JOIN Table2 AS b
ON a.field2 = b.field2;
```

The results using your sample data from these queries are:

```
field1 |  field2  | hasil
alfa     idAlfa      400
beta     idBeta      0
charlie  idCharlie   0
```

For future reference, the `IF` syntax you showed in your sample SQL is invalid. That is used in flow control statements that affect how SQL is executed; usually seen in stored procedures. `IF` can't be used in expressions. Instead, use `CASE` or `IIF` statements.